# Threshold does not work on numpy array for accuracy metric

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am trying to implement logistic regression from scratch using numpy. I wrote a class with the following methods to implement logistic regression for a binary classification problem and to score it based on BCE loss or Accuracy.

```py
  def accuracy(self, true_labels, predictions):
    """
    This method implements the accuracy score. Where the accuracy is the number 
    of correct predictions our model has.

    args:
      true_labels: vector of shape (1, m) that contains the class labels where,
      m is the number of samples in the batch.
      predictions: vector of shape (1, m) that contains the model predictions. 
    """
    
    counter = 0
    for y_true, y_pred in zip(true_labels, predictions):
      if y_true == y_pred:
        counter+=1
    
    return counter/len(true_labels)

  def train(self, score='loss'):
    """
    This function trains the logistic regression model and updates the 
    parameters based on the Batch-Gradient Descent algorithm.
    The function prints the training loss and validation loss on every epoch.

    args:
    X: input features with shape (num_features, m) or (num_features) for a 
       singluar sample where m is the size of the dataset.
    Y: gold class labels of shape (1, m) or (1) for a singular sample.

    """
    train_scores = []
    dev_scores = []
    for i in range(self.epochs):
      # perform forward and backward propagation & get the training predictions.
      training_predictions = self.propagation(self.X_train, self.Y_train)
      # get the predictions of the validation data

      dev_predictions = self.predict(self.X_dev, self.Y_dev)

      # calculate the scores of the predictions.
      if score == 'loss':  
        train_score = self.loss_function(training_predictions, self.Y_train)
        dev_score = self.loss_function(dev_predictions, self.Y_dev)
      elif score == 'accuracy':
        train_score = self.accuracy((training_predictions==+1).squeeze(), self.Y_train)
        dev_score = self.accuracy((dev_predictions==+1).squeeze(), self.Y_dev)
      
      train_scores.append(train_score)
      dev_scores.append(dev_score)
    plot_training_and_validation(train_scores, dev_scores, self.epochs, score=score)
```

after testing the code with the following input

```py
model = LogisticRegression(num_features=X_train.shape[0],
                           Learning_rate = 0.01,
                           Lambda = 0.001,
                           epochs=500,
                           X_train=X_train,
                           Y_train=Y_train,
                           X_dev=X_dev,
                           Y_dev=Y_dev,
                           normalize=False,
                           regularize = False,)
model.train(score = 'loss')
```

i get the following results
[image]

however when i swap the scoring metric to measure over time from loss to accuracy ass follows `model.train(score='accuracy')` i get the following result:
[image]
I have removed normalization and regularization to make sure i am using a simple implementation of logistic regression.

Note that i use an external method to visualize the training/validation score overtime in the `LogisticRegression.train()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick you are using to create your predictions before passing into the accuracy method is wrong. You are using `(dev_predictions==+1)`.
Your problem statement is a Logistic Regression model that would generate a value between 0 and 1. Most of the times, the values will NOT be exactly equal to +1.

So essentially, every time you are passing a bunch of `False` or `0` to the accuracy function. I bet if you check the number of classes in your datasets having the value `False or 0` would be :

1. exactly 51.7 % in validation dataset
2. exactly 56.2 % in training dataset.

To fix this, you can use a in-between threshold like 0.5 to generate your labels. So use something like `dev_predictions>0.5`

Comment: thanks it did not occur to me that the issue would be in how i apply the threshold to the raw predictions of the model. I edited the question to make it more obvious that the application of the threshold is the error that is causing this.